# What is the meaning of the word "matches"?

Tags: verbs, transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

I am studying regular expressions.

A regular expression is a pattern that you can *match* in a text. In books, I often read things like

> *the period `.` **matches** any single character.*

What is the definition of the word *matches* in this sentence?

There are two definitions that I've found that seem to be correct, but I'm not sure which one fits here:

- *to be equal, similar, suitable, or corresponding to in some way*: "his looks match his character"

and

- *to make, show, produce, or get a competitor, counterpart, or equivalent to*: "to match a piece of cloth"

I think the second definition makes more sense in this context since we're trying to find a pattern in the text.

Comment: Did you look [*match*](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Match&ls=a) up in a dictionary? What definitions did you find there that seem pertinent?

Comment: I have been looking up this word for the past week but haven't found my answer yet.

Comment: Of the definitions you found, which do you *suspect* might be applicable? And why? (Note: please [edit] this information into your question proper, rather than respond in a new comment.)

Comment: "to make, show, produce, or get a competitor, counterpart, or equivalent to: to match a piece of cloth" this is one definition that seems like is correct but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you include that detail in your question? Give us a quick explanation of why you think that definition is most relevant. If there are any other candidate definitions you came across, include those as well (along with  your rationale for each of them).

Comment: Does "matches" mean is equal to? What is the proper definition of this word? One that fits here?

Comment: I'm trying to show you how to get an answer to that question, here. If you follow the advice and instructions in my prior comments, you'll get the answer you're looking for. Asking the further questions (or even the same question ;) in comments will not. SE in general and EL&U in particular require querents to demonstrate independent effort and research before asking questions. Otherwise you give the impression of asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: @DanBron Uptick for the use of "querent," which sent me to the dictionary, which indeed defines the word as someone who asks but *specifically* of an astrologer.  Probably apt as I'm sure many new posters leave feeling -- rightly or wrongly -- that it would have been better to have consulted the stars.  "Querent" also has a rare usage meaning a complainer.  Also probably apt for many answerers.  The general and nearby word for an asker is "querist."

Comment: The problem is that "match", as used when discussing regular expressions, does not match the usual definitions of match.  The "corresponding" definition comes closest -- when you have a "match", the next character of the pattern is found to *correspond* to the next character of the string being examined.  This "correspondence" does not imply that the two values are equal, but that the examined character passes some test implied by the pattern character.  When this test is passed you have a "match".

Comment: @deadrat *querent*, n. **[an inquirer](http://www.onelook.com/?other=web1913&w=Querent)**; *querent*, n. **[one who asks a question](http://phrontistery.info/q.html)**. :) Onelook.com is a great tool to search multiple dictionaries at once. (And *querent* with the sense of complainer would be rendered "*querulous* person" today.)

Comment: @HotLicks Yep. See my answer.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks, I'll stick with the *OED*.  Call me old fashioned.

Comment: @deadrat As I was discussing with Josh here the other day, I'm an atheist, so I don't have any holy books. Much too limiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, bear in mind that a word's definitions are fuzzy, often metaphorical, and very frequently overlap. So it's perfectly possible that both the definitions you quoted, and possible more, apply.

That said, according to the premier online exponent of regexes in their various guises and incarnations, Jan Goyvaerts (creator of RegexBuddy and the regex coach), it is the first definition which is most applicable.

From his [primer on regexes](http://regular-expressions.mobi/tutorial.html):

> *A "**match**" is the piece of text, or sequence of bytes or characters that pattern was **found to correspond** to by the regex processing software*

In other words, the text *corresponds* to the pattern.

What does *correspond* mean then, you ask? We can say what pattern *matches* is precisely *the class, set, or category of strings* the pattern delineates. Or, another way to think about a pattern is as a *filter* or sieve: you may pass any arbitrary string to a regex, and those that it lets through we call *matches*.

To elevate the question above the field of text processing, let the word "mammal" represent the sub-category of vertebrates that have body hair, live births, and express milk (an [oversimplification](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammal), of course).

Then the pattern "mammal" *matches* bears, dogs, dolphins, and humans. It does *not match* geckos, roaches, amoebas, or tuna.

Similarly, the regex pattern `[0-9]+` *matches* `6`, `4`, `99`, and `123987`. It *does not match* `q`, `banana`, `12lol34`, or .

Finally, the regex `.` *matches* any single character (with some caveats about newline characters depending on engine and configuration) , but would *not match* the absence of a character.

Comment: If you could replace the word matches in the following sentence with another phrase that would really help out: the regex . matches any single character.

Comment: @AsadMoosvi Sure: *the pattern would be satisfied by* or *the filter would let through*.

Comment: I asked Steven Levithan, the author of Regular Expressions Cookbook, and he said it means "to find a match for."

Comment: @AsadMoosvi Haha, that's too precious. I love it. Did you see [@HotLicks' comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275324/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-word-matches#comment607839_275324)  that a pattern is a "test" and a match is a string which passes the test? Thought that quite apt.

Comment: It also feels like "finds a match for" is the best definition for "matches" in "the period . matches any single character" since we are trying to find a match for that pattern.

Comment: @AsadMoosvi Sure, but doesn't that just raise the question of what it means to "find a match for"? That's just a rephrasing of "matches".

Comment: No, it doesn't since you've already defined what the word "match" means in your answer.